# Is this an automatic setting within Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, macbook-pro

I have recently bought a MacBook Pro and immediately noticed that, unlike every Windows OS I've worked with, a Google option constantly pops up when I start to type and often blocks the screen.

This large box-screen follows my cursor and if I click away, it returns repeatedly.

Is this a system-wide setting specifically for Macs and is there any way to turn it off?

I haven't found any help in the settings for Chrome and it's increasingly prevalent.

Comment: what Google option? A screenshot would help.

Comment: I'll shoot one as soon as it happens again.  In fact, I'll just open a search.  If I may ask, as a novice Mac user, what is the command for screen captures?